# Blend tree in animator controller how can I change between animations smooth?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

This is a screenshot of the blend tree. The top first animation is idle and on the left side bottom there is a Forward and I added also a Forward parameter. This Forward controls the player's movement speed.

[image: Blend tree settings]

and with this script attached to the player, I'm controlling the Forward parameter and slow down the player movement.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerSpaceshipAreaColliding : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotationSpeed =250;
    public float movingSpeed;
    public float secondsToRotate;
    public GameObject uiSceneText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI textMeshProUGUI;

    private float timeElapsed = 0;
    private float lerpDuration = 3;
    private float startValue = 1;
    private float endValue = 0;
    private float valueToLerp = 0;
    private Animator playerAnimator;
    private bool exitSpaceShipSurroundingArea = false;
    private bool slowd = true;
    private bool startRotatingBack = false;
    private bool displayText = true;

    private float desiredRot;
    public float damping = 10;
    private Rigidbody playerRigidbody;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        playerRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        desiredRot = transform.eulerAngles.y;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (exitSpaceShipSurroundingArea)
        {
            if (slowd)
                SlowDown();

            if (playerAnimator.GetFloat("Forward") == 0)
            {
                slowd = false;

                LockController.PlayerLockState(false);

                if (displayText)
                {
                    uiSceneText.SetActive(true);

                    if (textMeshProUGUI.text != "")
                        textMeshProUGUI.text = "";

                    textMeshProUGUI.text = "I can see something very far in the distance, but it's too long to walk by foot.";

                    StartCoroutine(UITextWait());

                    displayText = false;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator UITextWait()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);

        textMeshProUGUI.text = "";
        uiSceneText.SetActive(false);
        startRotatingBack = true;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.name == "CrashLandedShipUpDown")
        {
            exitSpaceShipSurroundingArea = false;
            Debug.Log("Entered Spaceship Area !");
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.name == "CrashLandedShipUpDown")
        {
            exitSpaceShipSurroundingArea = true;
            Debug.Log("Exited Spaceship Area !");
        }
    }

    private void SlowDown()
    {
        if (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
        {
            valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
            playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
            timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        }

        playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
        valueToLerp = 0;
    }
}
```

The problem is when Forward gets to value 0 and the player stops its kind of jumping to the idle animation in the blend tree and not smooth changing to it.

The value of the idle animation (Changes animation speed) in the inspector I marked with a red circle was 1 like the rest but because it was kind of jumping to the idle I changed it to 0.5 but now the whole idle animation is playing too slow like in slow motion.

I'm not sure why it's jumping the change from the slow down to the idle is looks like it's cutting jumping to it and not smoothly change to the idle animation ?

Comment: I found a solution. Inside the script ThirdPersonUserControl instead, disable it as I did in the line LockController.PlayerLockState(false); I just added to the ThirdPersonUserControl script a public static bool and when it's true it will not allow using the inputs in the FixedUpdate.  That's working great now.

Comment: If you think you found a solution for such problem please don't comment but answer your question properly so a) people can see that this already had an answer and b) someone with a similar issue can find a solution better

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me.

Inside the script ThirdPersonUserControl instead of disabling the whole script like I'm doing in the line LockController.PlayerLockState(false); I just added a public static bool and by setting the bool to true it will avoid using the input's in the script :

The new bool variable is name stop :

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof (ThirdPersonCharacter))]
    public class ThirdPersonUserControl : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private ThirdPersonCharacter m_Character; // A reference to the ThirdPersonCharacter on the object
        private Transform m_Cam;                  // A reference to the main camera in the scenes transform
        private Vector3 m_CamForward;             // The current forward direction of the camera
        private Vector3 m_Move;
        private bool m_Jump;                      // the world-relative desired move direction, calculated from the camForward and user input.

        public static bool stop = false;

        
        private void Start()
        {
            // get the transform of the main camera
            if (Camera.main != null)
            {
                m_Cam = Camera.main.transform;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning(
                    "Warning: no main camera found. Third person character needs a Camera tagged \"MainCamera\", for camera-relative controls.", gameObject);
                // we use self-relative controls in this case, which probably isn't what the user wants, but hey, we warned them!
            }

            // get the third person character ( this should never be null due to require component )
            m_Character = GetComponent<ThirdPersonCharacter>();
        }


        private void Update()
        {
            if (!m_Jump)
            {
                m_Jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump");
            }
        }


        // Fixed update is called in sync with physics
        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            if (stop == false)
            {
                // read inputs
                float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
                float v = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");
                bool crouch = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C);

                // calculate move direction to pass to character
                if (m_Cam != null)
                {
                    // calculate camera relative direction to move:
                    m_CamForward = Vector3.Scale(m_Cam.forward, new Vector3(1, 0, 1)).normalized;
                    m_Move = v * m_CamForward + h * m_Cam.right;
                }
                else
                {
                    // we use world-relative directions in the case of no main camera
                    m_Move = v * Vector3.forward + h * Vector3.right;
                }
#if !MOBILE_INPUT
                // walk speed multiplier
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) m_Move *= 0.5f;
#endif

                // pass all parameters to the character control script
                m_Character.Move(m_Move, crouch, m_Jump);
                m_Jump = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my script, the player is slow down stop and then not moving and it's changing smoothly to the idle animation because it's doing it already in the blend tree the problem is not with the blend tree but was with the way I tried to lock the player from moving.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;

public class PlayerSpaceshipAreaColliding : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotationSpeed =250;
    public float movingSpeed;
    public float secondsToRotate;
    public GameObject uiSceneText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI textMeshProUGUI;

    private float timeElapsed = 0;
    private float lerpDuration = 3;
    private float startValue = 1;
    private float endValue = 0;
    private float valueToLerp = 0;
    private Animator playerAnimator;
    private bool exitSpaceShipSurroundingArea = false;
    private bool slowd = true;
    private bool startRotatingBack = false;
    private bool displayText = true;

    public float damping = 10;
    private Quaternion playerRotation;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (exitSpaceShipSurroundingArea)
        {
            if (slowd)
                SlowDown();

            if (playerAnimator.GetFloat("Forward") == 0)
            {
                slowd = false;

                ThirdPersonUserControl.stop = true;

                if (displayText)
                {
                    uiSceneText.SetActive(true);

                    if (textMeshProUGUI.text != "")
                        textMeshProUGUI.text = "";

                    textMeshProUGUI.text = "I can see something very far in the distance, but it's too long to walk by foot.";
                    StartCoroutine(UITextWait());
                    displayText = false;
                }
            }

            if (startRotatingBack)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, playerRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator UITextWait()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);

        textMeshProUGUI.text = "";
        uiSceneText.SetActive(false);
        startRotatingBack = true;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.name == "CrashLandedShipUpDown")
        {
            exitSpaceShipSurroundingArea = false;
            Debug.Log("Entered Spaceship Area !");
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.name == "CrashLandedShipUpDown")
        {
            playerRotation = transform.rotation;

            exitSpaceShipSurroundingArea = true;
            Debug.Log("Exited Spaceship Area !");
        }
    }

    private void SlowDown()
    {
        if (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
        {
            valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
            playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
            timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        }

        playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
        valueToLerp = 0;
    }
}
```